# How to make a printable form using javafx

Tags: pdf, javafx, javafx-2, pdf-generation

I am developing a project. Am doing it in javafx using NetBeans IDE. Also I use MySQL as the back-end. I want to generate a printable form of my output. How can I do it ? Can anyone describe the steps or provide a good tutorial ?

Comment: Will taking a snapshot of your scene and printing it out help ? If not, you may design you own pdf reports using JasperReports or any other tool, from the data you are showing on your form and then print it out !

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Is it possible to create a PDF using javafx ? Thats what I want to know.

Comment: Directly from javafx, No !

Comment: @ItachiUchiha What is this JasperReports ?

Comment: Jasper Reports is a Java based open source Reporting Framework, in which you can make reports on PDF, EXCEL etc from the same design ! For more information. you can visit http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library. As far as I know, it is based on iText http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/

Comment: What am planning is to read data from database and make a PDF. Which is the easy way to do it in javafx ?

Comment: Lets continue the conversation here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48710/javafx

Comment: another possibility is to use https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/ .from a java bean you can generate a report as pdf, word ....

Comment: Could you clarify the use case? Are you simply looking to create a PDF in order to print it, but You don't really care that it's a PDF, or do you want to create an interactive PDF?

Comment: @OJKrylow Like you said I don't really care that's a PDF. What I need is a form that can be printed. It can be PDF, word format or anything other. I prefer the easiest way to do it, that's all I want.

Comment: https://carlfx.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/introduction-by-example-javafx-8-printing/